# shell_exec(sudo service apache2 restart) only stops the server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, debian, server

I tried to restart my Apache2 Server with PHP with this command:

```
shell_exec("sudo service apache2 restart");
```

Apache stops but don't start...

Btw:

```
shell_exec("sudo service apache2 reload");
```

works for me... I use Debian on my Server

Apache2 Error Log:

```
    [Sun May 17 19:55:18 2015] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sun May 17 19:55:18 2015] [error] (9)Bad file descriptor: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Sun May 17 19:55:18 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.39-0+deb7u2 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1e configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 17 20:03:46 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Comment: Does it work when you invoke it via command line?

Comment: You should log the result with `print`

Comment: See here: https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/apache-error-bad-file-descriptor-apr_socket_accept.26571/

Comment: As I understand it, yes.